# c++ unhandled exception access violation at assigning variable

Tags: c++, memory, vector

```
std::vector <Item*> itemSlot;
itemSlot.resize(1);

Item testItem;
testItem.item_id = 99;

*itemSlot[0] = testItem;        // ERROR

std::cout << "ID: " << itemSlot[0]->item_id << std::endl;
```

Why do I get an error?

I know I can do it with:

```
itemSlot[0] = &testItem;
```

but I do not want to do it this way, because if I create the item in a function and assign it in a function it would give me random number if I call itemSlot[0]->item_id outside the function because the variable item would get destroyed and the pointer would point to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of

```
*itemSlot[0] = testItem; // Copy-assign testItem into the item at index zero
```

is entirely different from

```
itemSlot[0] = &testItem; // Place the address of testItem at index zero
```

The first construct would work if you had an `Item` at index zero, but you don't: the call to `itemSlot.resize(1)` places `nullptr` into index zero, so dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.

There are several solutions available:

- Make your `vector` a vector of `Item` instead of `Item*`, or
- Use `Item *testItem = new Item()` and call `delete` at the end, or
- Use `new Item()` with a vector of smart pointers to avoid manual deletion.

Comment: You're thinking of `reserve(1)`, `resize(1)` does change the size of the vector.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You are absolutely right, I edited to correct this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have got vector of pointers to items. It's a generally bad idea to do so. Shared pointers would be better. If you want to use pointers, then you should allocate memory for them, so you should do:

```
itemSlot[0] = new Item;
```

before accessing it. And even better looking would be:

```
Item* tmpItem = new Item;
itemSlot.push_back(tmpItem);
```

And do not forget to free memory afterwards. use shared pointers or unique pointers instead

---

Another way:

```
itemSlot[0] = &testItem;
```

This is also ok, but after testItem stops existing vector will be still pointing to some place in memory.